# authentication+acl in zend framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework2, bootstrapping

Hello I managed to implement acl and authentication in ZF2, but now I have two main problems. I am cannot redirect the user after he is/is not logged in (in bootstrap file) and my another mission is to do query to mysql because I have to check user permissions, after he is logged in. This code bellow is all Module.php. Can you help me? To now I did login form an it works good.(it works without acl for now)

```
namespace Application;

use Zend\Mvc\ModuleRouteListener;
use Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent;

use Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\AutoloaderProviderInterface;
use Zend\Authentication\Storage;
use Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationService;
use Zend\Authentication\Adapter\DbTable as DbTableAuthAdapter;
class Module
{
    protected $loginTable;
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
{
    $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('translator');
    $eventManager        = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();
    $moduleRouteListener = new ModuleRouteListener();
    $moduleRouteListener->attach($eventManager);

    $this -> initAcl($e);
    $e -> getApplication() -> getEventManager() -> attach('route', array($this, 'checkAcl'));


        $app = $e->getApplication();
        $locator = $app->getServiceManager();
        $authAdapter = $locator->get('AuthService');

        if($authAdapter->hasIdentity() === true){
        //is logged in
        }else{
                //user is not logged in...redirect to home
        }


}

public function getConfig()
{
    return include __DIR__ . '/config/module.config.php';
}

public function getAutoloaderConfig()
{
    return array(
        'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
            'namespaces' => array(
                __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . __NAMESPACE__,
            ),
        ),
    );
}


 public function getServiceConfig() {

    return array(
        'factories' => array(
            'AuthService' => function($sm) {

                $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
                $dbTableAuthAdapter = new DbTableAuthAdapter($dbAdapter, 'user', 'username', 'password', 'MD5(?)');

                $authService = new AuthenticationService();
                $authService->setAdapter($dbTableAuthAdapter);


                return $authService;
            },
        ),
    );
}


public function initAcl(MvcEvent $e) {

    $acl = new \Zend\Permissions\Acl\Acl();
    $roles = include __DIR__ . '/config/module.acl.roles.php';
    $allResources = array();
    foreach ($roles as $role => $resources) {

        $role = new \Zend\Permissions\Acl\Role\GenericRole($role);
        $acl -> addRole($role);

        $allResources = array_merge($resources, $allResources);

        //adding resources
        foreach ($resources as $resource) {
            $acl -> addResource(new \Zend\Permissions\Acl\Resource\GenericResource($resource));
        }
        //adding restrictions
        foreach ($allResources as $resource) {
            $acl -> allow($role, $resource);
        }
    }
    //testing
    //var_dump($acl->isAllowed('admin','home'));
    //true

    //setting to view
    $e -> getViewModel() -> acl = $acl;

}

public function checkAcl(MvcEvent $e) {
    $route = $e -> getRouteMatch() -> getMatchedRouteName();

    $userRole = 'guest';

    if (!$e -> getViewModel() -> acl -> isAllowed($userRole, $route)) {
        $response = $e -> getResponse();
        //location to page or what ever
        $response -> getHeaders() -> addHeaderLine('Location', $e -> getRequest() -> getBaseUrl() . '/404');
        $response -> setStatusCode(303);

    }
}


}
```

Comment: This is just a hint, i don't know if you know about them, but there's two great Module out there that do exactly this. They are called ZfcUser and BjyAuthorize. You may wanna look out for them. Seeing how they work may also help you with your problem.

Comment: Now I am trying to learn ZF2 and I want to do all alone. I want to understand how exactly works ZF2. This is my main idea. I want maybe somebody find my gaps and help me and after that I can continue working.

Answer (score 0):

here is some example of my codes :

```
$controller = $e->getTarget();
$auth = new AuthenticationService();
$is_login = $auth->hasIdentity();

//check if action is login

$params = $e->getApplication()->getMvcEvent()->getRouteMatch()->getParams();

if ($params['action'] == 'login') {

if ($is_login) {
    return $controller->redirect()->toRoute('adminwithlang/adminindex');
}

if (!$is_login) {
return $controller->redirect()->toRoute('adminwithlang/adminauthlogin');
}
```

example gist :
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5227267

Comment: or you can use BjyAuthorize + ZFCUSER modules ...  i didnt use them because of performance

Comment: This code may be will work in controller but in Module.php it doesn`t work. The redirect() is undefined and getParams() too. I want to check for user authentication in bootstrap because this will work for every Module.If i do this in bootstrap I don`t need to check if user id logged in in every module.

Comment: I copy it from my module.php ...  here is my complete module.php -> https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5227267

Comment: Thank you everybody. I find the answer of my problem. Just to share I did redirect with this code:                          $response -> getHeaders() -> addHeaderLine('Location', $e -> getRequest() -> getBaseUrl() . '/');
$response -> setStatusCode(303);

Comment: How I can do it? Can you share me better way, because I didn`t find better way?

Comment: Use controller redirect instead of that messy redirect

Answer (score 0):

I am looking at something similar to this; I did some digging and found the following

get the following inside the function you attach on the onBootstrap

```
$routeMatch = $e->getRouteMatch( );
$controllerParamName = \Zend\Mvc\ModuleRouteListener::ORIGINAL_CONTROLLER;
$controller = $routeMatch->getParam( $controllerParamName );
$action = $routeMatch->getParam( 'action' );
$route = $routeMatch->getMatchedRouteName( );
```

check if the user has logged in; if not you are redirecting to the login event

while redirecting you can pass these 3 variables (controller, action, route)
inside your login event these will default to null
and if they are defined then after successful login you will redirect to this combination of controller, action, route

I am still writing the code and I will publish once I am successful
Hope this helps